# Evaluating $\lim_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \frac{ \ln(x+e^y)-x-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How can I compute such a limit:
  $$\lim_{(x,y) \to(0,0)}  \frac{ \ln(x+e^y)-x-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$?

Comment: If you set x to 0, the function is identically 0 for all values of y. Now, set y to 0 and take the limit as x -> 0. If it's also 0, the limit exists and is 0. If that limit isn't 0, the limit does not exist.

Comment: @barrycarter: That is not enough to conclude that the limit exists. For example, $$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} $$ passes your two tests but the limit does not exist.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You're right, I'm wrong. Of course, the limit has to exist from every direction. I should've said that those two limits existing is a necessary condition, but not a sufficient one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $\log(x+e^y)$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ with gradient $(1,1)$, so
$$ \log(x+e^y) = x+y+o(x,y) $$

Comment: So this limit is 0?

Comment: @dreamer94: Yes. In fact, in some formulations, this limit being $0$ is chosen as _definition_ of what it means for $\log(x+e^y)$ to be differentiable with gradient $(1,1)$ -- and we then prove separately that functions of several variables are differentiable if their partial deriviatives are nice enough (which they are here).

Comment: I see, thanks for help and spelling out.